# Exchange Crashes, CRUSHES all mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

My exchange server took a massive dump yesterday and I simply don't have the time to recover it for only 2 users. I am left with only the offline OST files that are locally stored on the client machines. Is there anyway I can recover emails, calendars etc with only this OST file?

Comment: Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/5229/is-there-any-way-to-restore-a-pst-outlook-personal-folder-or-ost-offline